# How to sort asc a date array in javascript? format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i sort asc an array with multiples dates? in format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"

```
[
        '10/07/2021 16:00',
        '29/06/2021 21:00',
        '26/06/2021 11:00',
        '17/07/2021 17:00',
        '07/07/2021 13:00',
        '29/06/2021 20:00',
        '30/06/2021 10:00',
        '19/07/2021 06:00',
        '13/07/2021 22:00',
        '24/06/2021 18:00',
        '04/07/2021 06:00',
        '22/06/2021 08:00'
]
```

i tried the following codes, both didn't work.

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.split('/').reverse().join('')
    b = b.split('/').reverse().join('')
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0
                
})


array.sort((a, b) => a.valueOf() - b.valueOf())
```

Comment: How did you try to solve this? Do you have any code?

Comment: array.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.split('/').reverse().join('')
    b = b.split('/').reverse().join('')
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0
    
   })

Comment: how about posting the code as text so folks can take a crack at it?

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: What does _"both didn't work"_ mean? Your arrays contains strings. They are lexicographically sorted. _"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."_ Probably you should add some more details so that we don't have to ask for everything.

Comment: does the end result need to be in the same format as the original?

Comment: @Kinglish yes dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run each through a date-formatter in sort

```js
let date_obj = [
  '10/07/2021 16:00',
  '29/06/2021 21:00',
  '26/06/2021 11:00',
  '17/07/2021 17:00',
  '07/07/2021 13:00',
  '29/06/2021 20:00',
  '30/06/2021 10:00',
  '19/07/2021 06:00',
  '13/07/2021 22:00',
  '24/06/2021 18:00',
  '04/07/2021 06:00',
  '22/06/2021 08:00'
]

//DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm
const formatDate = d => {
  d = d.split(" ").flatMap(e => e.split("/").flatMap(f => f.split(":"))) ;
  return `${d[2]}-${d[1]}-${d[0]} ${d[3]}:${d[4]}`;
}

let dates = date_obj.sort((a, b) => new Date(formatDate(a)) - new Date(formatDate(b)))
console.log(dates)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kinglish , it worked!!! people are very toxic here, you're awesome bro!

Comment: As general advice, you shouldn't store the string representation of anything unless you have to. Strings should be parsed into an internal format on input, and formatted on output. Otherwise every time you want to do something with it (like sorting), you need to break it down somehow in addition to the processing you want.